# tank and pipes problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A tank of 425 liters capacity has been filled with water through two pipes, the first pipe having been opened 5 hours longer than the second. If the first pipe were open as long as the second pipe, the first pipe deliver half the amount of water delivered by second pipe; if the two pipes were open simultaneously, the tank would be filled up in 17 hours. How long was the second pipe open?

- a. 10
- b. 12
- c. 15
- d. 18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x = first pipe rate
y = second pipe rate
a = hours of second pipe

$$y = 2x\\
17(x+y) = 425\\
x+y = 25\\
3x = 25\\
x = \frac{25}{3}, y = \frac{50}{3}\\
(a+5)\frac{25}{3} + a\frac{50}{3} = 425\\
(a+5) + 2a = 51\\
3a + 5= 51\\
3a = 46\\
a = 46/3$$

Are you allowed rounding?

Comment: thanks a lot...yes rounding is allowed